Cannot use exported method that belongs to the package in Golang
I've got a package named services. This is the structure of the package:
services/
    third_party/
       discogs.go
       discogsAPIStructs.go
    artist_srv.go
    auth_srv.go
    record_srv.go

My artists' service looks like the following:
package services

import (
    "championshipVinyl/entities"
    "championshipVinyl/forms"
    "championshipVinyl/utils"
    "encoding/json"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "go.uber.org/zap"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

// ArtistService a service representation.
type ArtistService struct {
    Artists []entities.Artist
    db      *gorm.DB
}

// NewArtistService creates a new instance of a category service.
func NewArtistService(db *gorm.DB) *ArtistService {
    return &ArtistService{
        Artists: nil,
        db:      db,
    }
}

func (as ArtistService) FindByName(name string) (entities.BaseEntity, error) { ... }

Now, services/third_party/discogs.go is the following:
package services

import (
    "championshipVinyl/entities"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

type DiscogsAPI struct {
    db *gorm.DB
}

func NewDiscogsAPI(db *gorm.DB) *DiscogsAPI {
    return &DiscogsAPI{
        db: db,
    }
}

I'm trying to add a method to the previous file, but when instantiating the artists' service (NewArtistService) I'm getting an error:
func (da DiscogsAPI) fetchArtist(name string) (entities.BaseEntity, error) {
    s := NewArtistService(da.db)
    fmt.Println(s)
    artist := entities.Artist{}
    return artist, nil 
}

the error says:

Unresolved reference 'NewArtistService'

Why am I getting this error? I mean, NewArtistService belongs to the same package where the call is being performed.
If I change
s := NewArtistService(da.db)

by
s := services.NewArtistService(da.db)

the error goes away, but when compiling I get a import cycle error which is expected, I mean, I'm trying to import services in a file within the package.

Where do you import "services" or the moral equivalent?

sorry, not following your question. If I simply call NewArtistService(da.db) I'm not supposed to do import "services" since they all live under the same package, right? If I do s := services.NewArtistService(da.db) then the import statement (import "services") is added on the list of imports at the top of the file, but when compiling I'm getting the import cycle error

You have to import your package if you want its functionality in any other package.  I'm assuming the first code sample you showed is in artist_srv.go, so that's a distinct package from the third party code snippet you showed.

Right, you're correct when you say  if you want its functionality in any other package, but the thing is that both files belong to the same package. The files within third_party as well as artist_srv.go belong to the same package, the all have on top package services

The full path actually matters, all the way down to what shows up in go.mod, not just the last bit.  This prevents conflicts since lots of repositories have a services package.

If I use import "services" in services/third_party/discogs.go then I get import cycle not allowed

[Edit] your question with a [mcve], including go.mod so that it can be reproduced.

All packages are distinct and separate. You are free to organise them on disc however you wish, e.g. to illuminate relationships for ease of maintenance. But how packages are organised on disc has no bearing on any relationship between the packages as far as the compiler is concerned (with the exception of folder names with specific, documented purposes such as internal and testdata).
In simple terms, in your case, you have 2 (TWO) distinct and unrelated packages:

services
third_party

The fact that the third_party package is maintained as a folder within the folder containing the services package does not give the third_party package code access to the symbols exported by the services package; third_party code must import the services package explicitly and qualify the required exported symbols as usual:
func (da DiscogsAPI) fetchArtist(name string) (entities.BaseEntity, error) {
    s := services.NewArtistService(da.db)
    // ...

The import cycle this creates is not necessarily predictable based solely on the organisation of the packages on disc; it depends solely on the import relationships between the packages, regardless of the file system organisation.
i.e., if the services package contains code that imports' third_party, ' then third_party code cannot import services without creating that (illegal) import cycle.
How to Fix
It is difficult to say without a broader understanding and appreciation for your project. Still, in my experience, when a package in a subfolder takes a dependency on the package it is organised within (the 'parent' package if you like, though remember there is no such parent-child relationship beyond the file system), that is usually a code smell indicating that the package organization needs to be reviewed and revised.
The fact that an import cycle exists between the two packages is effectively confirmation that you either do not have the separate packages that you think you do (everything belongs in the services package) or you have not sufficiently decoupled the relationship between services and the third_party dependencies.
There is no single solution to this problem.
Only you can fix this - or someone with a similarly comprehensive grasp of the wider project - by refactoring your code to address the cyclic dependency that currently exists.
A Potential Approach
Use inversion of control.
(e.g.) Instead of constructing an ArtistsService using the DiscogsAPI struct, provide a reference in the API struct to an interface that describes the functionality required of an Artists service.
A DiscogsAPI struct is then initialised with an implementation of that interface by whatever code uses the Discogs API:
// in third_party/discogsAPIStructs.go
type DiscogsAPI struct {
    Artists interface { FindByName(string) (*entities.BaseEntity, error) }
    DB *gorm.DB
}

// in services...
asvc := ArtistsService{DB: myDB}
dapi := third_party.DiscogsAPI{Artists: asvc, DB: myWB}


in the above illustration I have eliminated the New..() factory funcs by simply exporting fields requiring initialisation.  This may or may not be appropriate, a qualification that applies to the approach as a whole. :)

Whether this or some other approach is best in your case only you can decide.
